# I want to make a single asynctask class that asynctask can manipulate String, Integer, URL

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to make a single asynctask class. That asynctask can manipulate String, Integer, URL. When I pass String to it then Asynctask manipulates the string data. When I pass Integer data to it then it manipulates it respectively. Please suggest me if it is possible with a single asynctask or do I need to make three different Asynctasks to manipulate different types of data ? Thanks.

Comment: what actually you want to do ?

Comment: @quicklearner i have String,Integer, URL data so i can make three asynctask to manipulate  different type of data . so my question is  ,  is this possible with single asynctask or not.

Comment: i got your point but i want to know what actually you are trying to implement ?

Comment: somebody ask this question to me so tell me is this possible with single asynctask or not.if yes how or not why?

Comment: there are other alternatives like using loaders,service class etc